Singularities and their nature
What are the singularities of $f(z) = e^{\frac{\sin z}{z}}$ ?
It clearly has a removable singularity at $0$. A textbook says that it has essential singularities at $kπ$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. How and why ? If it was $f(z) = e^{\frac{z}{\sin z}}$ then I can see how but not in this case.

That textbook is wrong.

@Martin Thanks a lot for confirmation. I just spend more than a hour utterly confused.

@Martin Sorry to bother you again, I have attached the image of the question. Is there any way I could have misinterpreted it?
https://i.imgur.com/n7tte53.jpeg

@Martin Ex. 9.1.28

That is definitely wrong in the book. I assume (as you did) that it is a typo and the author meant  $f(z) = e^{z/\sin(z)}$.

@Anonymous Also, suggesting to draw a picture of that. That hurts
